# Сокращение document.all?1:0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Вопрос чисто из любопытства: часто в коде встречаю такую конструкцию - **var ie = document.all?1:0;** Если заранее известно, что переменная ie будет использоваться только для проверки на true/false, не проще ли ее объявить **var ie = document.all;** ? В чем разница-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае, если document.all определен, в переменную ie запишется document.all, а не true. Тернарный оператор делают, чтобы не таскать в переменной ie объект.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, это ближе к истине: множество приведений типа заменяется одним, в самом начале. К слову, в ie таскается не объект, а ссылка на объект. <script>alert(document.all['b']);var a = document.all;a['b'] = 1;alert(document.all['b']);</script> - проверьте в ИЕ.

Comment: Конечно ссылка, в js объекты передаются всегда по ссылке. Насколько я знаю, встроенного "клонирования" объектов в js нет, только пользовательские реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше тогда

> var ie = !!document.all;

А ещё лучше вообще не использовать проверки на определённый браузер, да и к IE это всё не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Я к тому, что: нужны ли все эти приведения типа и лишние действия при написании понятного кода? Тем более, что лучшая проверка на ИЕ, которую я встречал - это var ie = !-[1,]; от Aleko. А проверка на браузер бывает нужна, например, для динамической подгрузки стилей.

Comment: Лучше не делать проверку на браузер с помощью хаков :) Зачем вам вообще проверка на браузер?

Comment: Я бы не использовал приведение в выражениях типа if (navigator.geolocation) и использовал при сохранении в переменную.

А вместо динамической загрузки стилей для ИЕ лучше подключать их с помощью условных комментариев.

Comment: Чисто гипотетически, проверка пригодится при выводе информации на чужом сайте посредством вставки одного тега script (по тому же принципу, что и счетчики). Конкретной задачи пока нет, но всякий shit happens. Но что-то мы отошли от темы. Так есть ли разница между var ie = document.all?1:0; и var ie = document.all; ?